# Sass using @extend % from within a partial css file

Tags: sass

I have style.scss that imports

- _declarations.scss
- _button.scss

in _declarations.scss, I have a placeholder declaration of

```
%blah{
    colour: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Inside style.scss, I can have a selector like this

```
.extend_it{
    @extend %blah;
}
```

And the styles I'd expect are pulled into the .extend_it selector.

However if I try the same from within _button.scss I am unable to extend the %blah placeholder.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Is the `%blah` selector available from _button.scss?  What error does it give?

Comment: If the partial `_button.scss` is imported and used inside of the file that imports, then there should be no error

Comment: are you also importing _decarations.scss into _button.scss?